# Ubuntu 12.04. Show windows issue. Blank window appears

Tags: 12.04, unity, nvidia, compiz

I've got a problem with an action "show windows" which shows all windows when I reach a right down edge of my screen (similar to Expose at MAC).
Since I installed Ubuntu 12.04 this function has started making me problems. When I use it to check active apps and then I click on an app in a launcher which had been minimized when I used "show windows", only blank window appears. I must resize it to see the content. It's really annoying. My graphic card is NVidia GeForce 9600 GT. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I am having a similar issue. On an inconsistent basis, when I tab to an existing window, a blank window appears and, like you, I must resize to view its content. I also have an NVidia - GeForce GTX 560M - am using 12.04 too. This is a new problem since upgrading to 12.04.

Comment: I totally agree. I remember that this feature was perfect in Jaunty. It was possible to view all windows and when a cursor was on a thumbtail a window name was shown. It was even possible to zoom the thumbtail. Unfortunately these functions have disappeared over years. 
Back to the original issue - I just assume that it's a problem of graphics card support - drivers.

Comment: Just to clarify this further. I don't need to resize the window, I can just change workspaces and switch back and the window content is visible again.

Comment: That works for me too but it still doesn't solve the problem thoroughly.

Comment: 12.04 is EOL and OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years. VTC as `not reproducible`.

Comment: @Tarig We're going to close this. If somehow you're still looking for an answer to this question then you can [edit] the question to explain.